# removing margin for photo slider in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have integrated lately a slider in my website, originally i had a static photo, but now i replaced it with a photo slider, after i was able to do so, i had a margin around it where i couldn't locate it in order to remove it, and make the slider full screen,

I cannot locate and remove the margin around my featured homepage slider

can you please help me figure this out,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

`<div class="container">` is creating that margin.

you have to create the `slides` div outside the `container`.

give position it will work.

see the image attached for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the slider to be full-width of screen? If so, you'll have to remove the div class="container" that is wrapped around your slider. This is creating that margin.

Comment: if i remove it, it ruins everything

Comment: you have to create slides div outside the container. and give position it will work.

Comment: Don't remove the div entirely. Just remove the class name from that div.

Answer (score 0):

try out this code of your CSS

```
body,html

    {

   margin:0;
   padding:0;

    }
```